# Navigation Bar hidden by SVG

Tags: css, svg, plotly

I have a navigation bar with one element containing drop-down contents. The navigation bar code comes from the w3schools site. (http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_navbar.asp)
Below the menu I have added a SVG using *plotly* and it hides the drop-down contents.

Is there a way to make the navigation bar on the top (drop-down contents included) ?

(I have verified that by deleting the SVG, the drop-down contents isvisible)

Here is the sample code :

**HTML**

```
<ul>
  <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
<div id="myDiv" class="plotly" ></div>
```

**CSS**

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a, .dropbtn {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: red;
}

li.dropdown {
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5qktcvwb/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just added **z-index** property for the dropdown content and it's visible now.

```
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;    
    z-index: 1;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5qktcvwb/4/

Comment: Thank you, it works. Could you tell me what is z-index and the meaning of its value ?

Comment: @Robert Longson Thank you, I did not know this site, it is clear and helpful.

Comment: @oro777: You can also check out this post, it has the image that will give you a clear picture about the z-index order of all elements. http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/what-you-may-not-know-about-the-z-index-property--webdesign-16892